# TypeScript or JavaScript type casting

Tags: casting, typescript

How does one handle type casting in TypeScript or Javascript?

Say I have the following TypeScript code:

```
module Symbology { 

    export class SymbolFactory { 

        createStyle( symbolInfo : SymbolInfo) : any { 
            if (symbolInfo == null)
            {
                 return null;
            }

            if (symbolInfo.symbolShapeType === "marker") {      

                // how to cast to MarkerSymbolInfo          
                return this.createMarkerStyle((MarkerSymbolInfo) symbolInfo);
            }                                  
        }

        createMarkerStyle(markerSymbol : MarkerSymbolInfo ): any { 
            throw "createMarkerStyle not implemented";
        }              

    }
}
```

where `SymbolInfo` is a base class.  How do I handle typecasting from `SymbolInfo` to `MarkerSymbolInfo` in TypeScript or Javascript?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

You can cast like this:

```
return this.createMarkerStyle(<MarkerSymbolInfo> symbolInfo);
```

Or like this if you want to be compatible with tsx mode:

```
return this.createMarkerStyle(symbolInfo as MarkerSymbolInfo);
```

Just remember that this is a compile-time cast, and not a runtime cast.

Comment: Now, I see that in in doc, referred to as Type Assertions in section 4.13.

Comment: This answer does no longer provide the full picture of type assertion in typescript, whereas Alex's answer gives a more complete picture, and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @KristofferDorph This answer is 4 years old.  At the time of writing TypeScript was at version 0.8.1, and thus was the correct answer at the time.  JSX support was only included 3 years later.

Comment: @blorkfish that is true, but it is good practice to follow the times, so people asking the same question today gets the current answer, and not as it where 4 years ago :-)

Answer (score 246):

This is called [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in TypeScript, and since TypeScript 1.6, there are two ways to express this:

```
// Original syntax
var markerSymbolInfo = <MarkerSymbolInfo> symbolInfo;

// Newer additional syntax
var markerSymbolInfo = symbolInfo as MarkerSymbolInfo;
```

Both alternatives are **functionally identical**. The reason for introducing the `as`-syntax is that the original syntax conflicts with [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), see the design discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/296).

If you are in a position to choose, just use the syntax that you feel more comfortable with. I personally prefer the `as`-syntax as it feels more fluent to read and write.

Comment: How do you indicate to typescript that you have converted an object to another type? For example a func that returns type2, inside it it http gets type 1, does logic to convert, and returns what was type1 but is now type2?

Comment: @TonyGutierrez How do you do the conversion?

Comment: Basically take one property and modify. The only way I have found to do this is to create a new var (type2) and copy in the props from the type1var and then return it. You can't modify the type1 and return, or you get a "Can't cast" error.

Comment: "the original syntax conflicted with JSX" - I think "conflicts" would be a better wording, since the conflict is still there with the original syntax.

Answer (score 4):

In typescript it is possible to do an `instanceof` check in an if statement and you will have access to the same variable with the `Typed` properties.

So let's say `MarkerSymbolInfo` has a property on it called `marker`. You can do the following:

```
if (symbolInfo instanceof MarkerSymbol) {
    // access .marker here
    const marker = symbolInfo.marker
}
```

It's a nice little trick to get the instance of a variable using the same variable without needing to reassign it to a different variable name.

Check out these two resources for more information:

[TypeScript instanceof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) &
[JavaScript instanceof](https://javascript.info/instanceof)