# Cast object to interface in TypeScript

Tags: object, typescript, interface, casting

I'm trying to make a cast in my code from the body of a request in express (using body-parser middleware) to an interface, but it's not enforcing type safety.

This is my interface:

```
export interface IToDoDto {
  description: string;
  status: boolean;
};
```

This is the code where I'm trying to do the cast:

```
@Post()
addToDo(@Response() res, @Request() req) {
  const toDo: IToDoDto = <IToDoDto> req.body; // <<< cast here
  this.toDoService.addToDo(toDo);
  return res.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).end();
}
```

And finally, the service method that's being called:

```
public addToDo(toDo: IToDoDto): void {
  toDo.id = this.idCounter;
  this.todos.push(toDo);
  this.idCounter++;
}
```

**I can pass whatever arguments, *even ones that don't come close to matching the interface definition*, and this code will work fine.** I would expect, if the cast from response body to interface is not possible, that an exception would be thrown at runtime like Java or C#.

I have read that in TypeScript casting doesn't exist, only Type Assertion, so it will only tell the compiler that an object is of type `x`, so... Am I wrong? What's the right way to enforce and ensure type safety?

Comment: Please define "it's not working". Be precise. Is there an error? Which one? At compile-time? At runtime? What happens?

Comment: At runtime, the code executes normally, with whatever object I pass.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: My question is how to cast the incoming object to an a typed object. If the cast is not possible, throw an exception at runtime, like Java, C#...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript or JavaScript type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204759/typescript-or-javascript-type-casting)

Answer (score 253, accepted):

There's no casting in javascript, so you cannot throw if "casting fails".
Typescript [supports casting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) but that's only for compilation time, and you can do it like this:

```
const toDo = req.body as IToDoDto;
// or
const toDo = <IToDoDto> req.body; // deprecated
```

You can check at runtime if the value is valid and if not throw an error, i.e.:

```
function isToDoDto(obj: any): obj is IToDoDto {
    return typeof obj.description === "string" && typeof obj.status === "boolean";
}

@Post()
addToDo(@Response() res, @Request() req) {
    if (!isToDoDto(req.body)) {
        throw new Error("invalid request");
    }

    const toDo = req.body as IToDoDto;
    this.toDoService.addToDo(toDo);
    return res.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).end();
}
```

---

#### Edit

As @huyz pointed out, there's no need for the type assertion because `isToDoDto` is a type guard, so this should be enough:

```
if (!isToDoDto(req.body)) {
    throw new Error("invalid request");
}

this.toDoService.addToDo(req.body);
```

Comment: I don't think that you need the cast in `const toDo = req.body as IToDoDto;` since the TS compiler knows that it is an `IToDoDto` at this point

Comment: for anyone who is looking for type assertion in general, do not use <>. this is deprecated. use ```as```

Comment: "_There's no casting in javascript, so you cannot throw if "casting fails"._" I think, more to the point, interfaces in TypeScript are not actionable; in fact, they're 100% [syntatic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). They make it easier to maintain structures _conceptually_, but _have no actual impact on the transpiled code_ -- which is, imo, insanely confusing/anti-pattern, as OP's question evidences. There's no reason things that fail to match interfaces couldn't throw in transpiled JavaScript; it's a conscious (and poor, imo) choice by TypeScript.

Comment: @ruffin interfaces are not syntactic sugar, but they did make a conscious choice to keep it in runtime only. i think it's a great choice, that way there's no performance penalty at runtime.

Comment: [Tomayto tomahto](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tomato%3b+tomato)? The type safety from interfaces in TypeScript doesn't extend to your transpiled code, and even pre-runtime the type safety is _severely_ limited -- as we see in the OP's issue _where there is no type safety at all_. TS could say, "Hey, wait, your `any` isn't guaranteed to be `IToDoDto` yet!", but TS chose not to. If the compiler only catches _some_ type conflicts, **and none in the transpiled code** (and you're right; I should've been more clear @ that in the original), interfaces are unfortunately, imo, [mostly?] sugar.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another way to force a type-cast even between incompatible types and interfaces where TS compiler normally complains:

```
export function forceCast<T>(input: any): T {

  // ... do runtime checks here

  // @ts-ignore <-- forces TS compiler to compile this as-is
  return input;
}
```

Then you can use it to force cast objects to a certain type:

```
import { forceCast } from './forceCast';

const randomObject: any = {};
const typedObject = forceCast<IToDoDto>(randomObject);
```

Note that I left out the part you are supposed to do runtime checks before casting for the sake of reducing complexity. What I do in my project is compiling all my `.d.ts` interface files into JSON schemas and using `ajv` to validate in runtime.

Answer (score 10):

If it helps anyone, I was having an issue where I wanted to treat an object as another type with a similar interface. I attempted the following:

**Didn't pass linting**

```js
const x = new Obj(a as b);
```

The linter was complaining that `a` was missing properties that existed on `b`. In other words, `a` had some properties and methods of `b`, but not all. To work around this, I followed VS Code's suggestion:

**Passed linting and testing**

```js
const x = new Obj(a as unknown as b);
```

*Note that if your code attempts to call one of the properties that exists on type `b` that is not implemented on type `a`, you should realize a runtime fault.*

Comment: I'm glad I found this answer, but note that if you are sending 'x' over the network or to another app, you could be leaking personal info (if 'a' is a user for example), because 'x' still has all the properties of 'a', they are just unavailable for typescript.

Comment: @ZoltánMatók good point. Also, regarding sending the serialized object over the network there's [an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053103/typescript-what-is-better-get-set-properties/49053971#comment103513875_49053971) for Java style getters and setters over the JavaScript `get` and `set` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(api_output)) as BoxT;
```