# Typescript - What is better: Get / Set properties

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

Just recently discovered about using get and set keywords for class properties I was wondering what is the preferred method when using get / set for typescript classes:

```
class example {
    private a: any;
    private b: any;

    getA(): any{
        return this.a;
    }

    setA(value: any){
        this.a = value;
    }

    get b(): any{
        return this.b;
    }

    set b(value: any){
        this.b = value;
    }
}
```

I am just curious if there are any best practices, performance, or other factors.

Comment: u use get and set method when u want to validate value. this way is goodhttps://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html Accesors i think made it pretty clear

Comment: Is there a point of doing this? There's no business logic in those getter/setters it's cluttering the code making it harder to maintain. There are some performance impact in using getter/setter. The question is, what are you trying to encapsulate with this?

Comment: @12seconds: I am just asking if I should just use 'getProperty()' or 'get property()' with simple examples.

Comment: I come from OOP background, ideally you want to name what make sense. For example, does it make sense to do `Car.getModel` or `Car.Model`? For me, I'd go for `Car.Model`. So this question is really opinion based. There's no real answer to this.

Comment: One reason to prefer the get/set version is that it allows to use two-way data binding: `[(ngModel)]="b"`. With the methods, you have to split that into: `[ngModel]="getA()" (ngModelChange)="setA($event)"`. Please note that your variable name should be different from the property name (e.g. `private _b`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Getter and Setters have several uses, like**

> You can make a private variable read only, if you don't specify a setter

```
class example {
    private _a: any;

    get a(): any{
        return this._a;
    }
}
```

> You can use them to execute a custom logic when a variable changes, sort of a replacement for Event Emitter

```
class example {
    private _a: any;

    set a(value: any){
        this._a = value;

        // Let the world know, I have changed
        this.someMethod();
    }

    someMethod() {
        // Possibly a POST API call
    }
}
```

> You can use them to alias an output

```
class Hero {
    private _health: any = 90;

    get health(): string {
        if(this._health >= 50) {
            return "I am doing great!";
        } else {
            return "I don't think, I'll last any longer";
        }
    }
}
```

> A setter can be used for a clean assignment

```
class Hero {
    private _a: number;

    set a(val: number) {
        this._a = val;
    }

    setA(val: number) {
        this._a = val;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.a = 30;    // Looks cleaner
        this.setA(50);  // Looks Shabby, Method's purpose is to perform a logic not handle just assignments
    }
}
```

> Finally setter's biggest strength is the ability to check variables for proper value before assignment

```
class Hero {
    private _age: number;

    set age(age: number) {
        if (age > 0 && age < 100) {
            this._age = age
        } else {
            throw SomeError; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you can do all of this using the setAge of getAge and leaving the get and set keyword. I have a Java background and really want to know if there is a benefit in using the keywords. For me .getHealth() is more familiar and clearer than .health() . In my opinion .health() should return the actual value, I would write another function, something like getHealthInformation() and let that function return the string message. Just my opinion, could be completely wrong :D

Comment: @Jdruwe One potential reason to use traditional Java style getters and setters is when sending stringified versions of JavaScript objects (perhaps from an express powered REST API). Such an object would lose references to any other objects and functions (including the get and set methods) and its properties would all be prefixed with `_`; e.g. `_id`, `_name`. If we were to use `setId` and `getName` etc., our stringified JS object's properites would not have the underscore prefix (unless that's what we wanted).