# Generic way of checking if a value of an object is undefined so that the compiler understands it

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a type `T`:

```
type T = {
  akey: string | number | undefined
}
```

If I check specifically for it

```
const fun = (p: T) => {
  if(!p.akey) return
  p.akey.toString()
}
```

Typescript understands that `akey` can't be undefined.

If I do it generically though:

```
const fun2 = (p: T) => {
  if(Object.values(p).includes(undefined)) return
  p.akey.toString()
}
```

It does not: `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

How can I make typescript understand so I don't have to do:

`p.akey!.toString()`

Comment: What you call doing it generically doesn't actually check the key, hence typescript not knowing whether it's defined or not. Perhaps you could use Partial<MyType> and then after the check mark `p` as MyType?

Comment: @Webber What do you mean? The key `akey` itself will never be undefined cause it's required by `T` or am I missing something?

Comment: Exactly. Since you're doing `.includes()` I assume that any of the keys might be missing. If so, you can use `Partial<MyType>` where `interface MyType { akey: string | number }` or `interface MyType { [key: string]: string | number }`.

Comment: I've deleted my answer in favour of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43895205/3593896

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp9b7W) work for you? If so, I can write up an answer detailing why it works and how I came up with it. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @catgirlkelly thanks again for taking the time! Two question on a row you're solving me, I mean, it does what it's supposed to so I guess it answers my question, I do feel like it's an overkill, for now when I'm iterating which I need to do anything I'm checking in the loop the value. Which it's not what I would have liked, but I think this adds unnecessary complexity, I thought I was missing something obvious but maybe I'm not, I also have trouble searching for this.

Comment: I don't think this is overkill, far from it in fact. It's probably the most basic canonical solution there is.