# Cast not required in typescript when using instanceof?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using `instanceof` to check if an object is of a certain type.
I would expect that if this is true, I'd still need to cast that object to that certain type before I can use it as such.

But instead, inside the IF statement a cast seems not to be necessary. At least not in Visual Studio Code and in the [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

```
class Drink { 
    price: number = 4;
}

class Beer extends Drink { 
    alcohol: number = 6;
}

let array: Array<Drink> = new Array<Drink>();
array.push(new Drink(), new Beer(), new Drink());

for (let g of array) { 
    // here, only 'price' is available as a property of drink
    console.log(g.price);
    if (g instanceof Beer) {    
        // but unexpectedly, inside the IF statement
        // the alcohol value IS available!
        console.log(g.alcohol);

        // I expected I needed to cast drink to beer first:
        console.log((<Beer>g).alcohol);  
    }
}
```

Is this very smart behavior of the Typescript editor or is this a glitch?

Copy>Paste the above code in the [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to see this behavior...

Comment: there is no such thing as casting in typescript. You can assert that a value is of a type at compile time, but since the instance of part already does that the compiler is smart enough to assert it for you. ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript or JavaScript type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204759/typescript-or-javascript-type-casting)

Comment: No, but the answer below did :) The `if (g instanceof Beer)` already asserts the type so there no need to cast / assert it again inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a compiler feature called **type guards**, you can read more about it in the Advanced Types chapter of the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Also there is no such thing as casting in Typescript. What you can do is assert the type of a value at compile time and overwrite the type the compiler wants to assign to it.

In this case though it does it automatically for you.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember this is the [Type Guards](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#type-guards), available since v1.4:

> Type Guards
>
> A common pattern in JavaScript is to use typeof or instanceof to
>   examine the type of an expression at runtime. TypeScript now
>   understands these conditions and will change type inference
>   accordingly when used in an if block.