# Typescript: Cast an object to other type using. How? And instanceof or typeof?

Tags: typescript

Cast an object to other type using Typescript. How? And instanceof or typeof?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript or JavaScript type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204759/typescript-or-javascript-type-casting)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let object = myObject as string; // this way
let object = <string> myObject; // or this way
```

In addition, `instanceof` returns a boolean, `typeof` returns the instance type.

Answer (score 1):

"**Type Assertion**" as this is called in Typescript can be done as follows:

```
interface Student {   
    name: string;   
    code: number;   
}  
let student = <Student> { }; //or { } as student
student.name = "Rohit"; // Correct  
student.code = 123; // Correct
```

In the above example, we have created an interface Student with the properties name and code. Then, we used type assertion on the student, which is the correct way to use type assertion.

Use **typeof** for simple built in types:

```
true instanceof Boolean; // false
typeof true == 'boolean'; // true
```

Use **instanceof** for complex built in types:

```
[] instanceof Array; // true
typeof []; //object
```