# Reactive Forms correctly convert Form Value to Model Object

Tags: angular, typescript

While creating a Model Driven Template Reactive forms, when I create model object from Form Value. Then model object is loosing its TYPE.

For a Simple Example:

Model Class Book:

```
export class Book {
  public name: string;
  public isbn: string;
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.css']
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {

  bookFormGroup: FormGroup;
  private newBook: Book = new Book();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.bookFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      isbn: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addBook() {
    console.log('submit');
    this.newBook = <Book> this.bookFormGroup.value;
    console.log(this.newBook instanceof Book);
    console.log(this.newBook);
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="bookFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="addBook()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" >
    <input type="text" formControlName="isbn" >

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the above example, after filling `newBook` instance its converted to normal `Object`

i.e, 
After `this.newBook = <Book> this.bookFormGroup.value;`

`this.newBook instanceof Book` is becoming `FALSE`

How do I prevent this?
Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Note: I tried with `JSON.parse()` but it still same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204759/typescript-or-javascript-type-casting

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This constructor will work with any type and will assign any matching filed.

```
export class Book {
  public constructor(init?: Partial<Book>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

So you will be able to do this:

```
this.newBook = new Book(this.bookFormGroup.value);
```

This will save you a lot of work if the Book class will have any change in future and became bigger.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer,How do i make it work when my Book class extends another Class??

Comment: Just call empty super() in the constructor. The parent fields will apply as well.

Comment: Love this! Exactly what I need - thank you so much!

Comment: Don't forget that you must also parse child properties into their correct instance/type too (if that is what you want).

Comment: `this` is presenting the error: Argument type this is not assignable to parameter type ObjectConstructor

Answer (score 18):

I use spread operator:

```
this.newBook = {...this.newBook,...this.bookFormGroup.value}
```

Comment: Work only with attributs not with the function of the class

Comment: The form value which you will post to the server should not contain functions. @HawklmCG

Comment: I have several child components that all make up the model interface that I want to post to backend. Using this method, I could merge several forms that partially and sort of consecutively make up the model interface that I want to post.

```this.newBook = {...this.newBook, ...this.childForm1.bookFormGroup.value};
this.newBook = {...this.newBook, ...this.childForm2.someForm.value};```

where I have @ViewChild for my childForms.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say your model is like this:

```
export class Content {
    ID: number;
    Title: string;
    Summary: string;
}
```

Your component will look like this:

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {


  content: Content;
  contentForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {


    this.contentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Title: ['', Validators.required],
      Summary: ['', Validators.required]
    });.....
```

When the save button is called, you can merge the form builder object and the dto you have:

onContentFormSubmit() {

```
// stop here if form is invalid
if (this.contentForm.invalid) {
  return;
}

this.content = Object.assign(this.content, this.contentForm.value);
```

}

this.content will have the predefined values you have from onInit and the values from the from group.

Comment: This is helpful! Thanks so much!! +1

Answer (score 6):

1. You should have an interface and a class, and the class should implement the interface.
2. Create an empty book with an empty constructor.

   ```
   export class Book implements IBook {
     constructor(public name = '', public isbn = '') {}
   }
   ```
3. Create a real model-driven form.

   ```
   this.bookFormGroup = this.fb.group(new Book());
   ```
4. Correctly type your form

   ```
   this.newBook: IBook = this.bookFormGroup.value;
   ```

Comment: How do you add validation to bookFormGroup when we passed it a new Book() ?

Comment: I never faced the case, but there's an [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#question-form-components) that might help you. If I had to do it, I would create a class method that accepts a form group as a parameter, and thus can set the validators.

Answer (score 6):

```
let formData = this.formGroup.value as DataModel;
```

Comment: this is simple and good one

Answer (score 4):

you can try this in your `addBook()`:

```
 let formData = Object.assign({});
 formData = Object.assign(formData, this.bookFormGroup.value);
 this.newBook = new Book(formData.name ,formData.isbn );
 console.log(this.newBook instanceof Book);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your class definition to

```
export class Book {
  constructor(public name: string, public isbn: string) {}
}
```

Change your `addBook` method to

```
addBook() {
  const { name, isbn } = this.bookFormGroup.value;
  this.newBook = new Book(name, isbn);
  console.log(this.newBook instanceof Book);
  console.log(this.newBook);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a helper class with a static method like this:

```
export class ObjectAssigner {
  static create<T>(init: Partial<T>): T {
    const value = {};
    Object.assign(value, init);
    return value as T;
  }
```

With this way I can use it for both classes and interfaces like this:

```
const bookModel= ObjectAssigner.create<Book>(this.bookFormGroup.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used 'Partical class' to inject value through constractor of class.
this can be used when your form calls api and model needed to be passed in without casting or when you create new instance of model from reactive form value.

```
export class Address  {
  postCode: string;
  line1: string;
  line2: string;
  county: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
  cityId: string;
  countryId: string;

  constructor(initialValues: Partial<Address> = {}) {
    if (initialValues) {
      for (const key in initialValues) {
        if (initialValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           this[key] = initialValues[key];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and create the formGroup directly to model, solved the problem.
In your code:

```
  this.bookFormGroup = this.fb.group(Book);
```

Book is the class name of your model.

Comment: How do you handle FormGroup validations (i.e. front-end exposed properties of the book) ?

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
this.formGroupSubscription = this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
    let mappedObject: MyCreateDTO = form;

    // do stuff with mappedObject.myproperty
});
```