# Can we create model classes (DTOs) for Angular reactive forms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular6

In MVC or Rest APIs we have model classes (DTOs) to transfer data. How can we create those model classes and use them for reactive forms in Angular?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997765/reactive-forms-correctly-convert-form-value-to-model-object

Answer (score 1):

I have used the package(@rxweb/reactive-form-validators) in my project for model based reactive form validation.

For your understanding I have copied the code from the stackbliz example of repective article "[**New way to validate the reactive forms**](https://medium.com/@oojhaajay/new-way-to-validate-the-angular-reactive-form-2c4fe4f13373)"

You can define the validation on top of the property through validation decorators. See the below code User class and applied @required validation decorator.

```js
import { required,compare } from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators";

export class User {

    @required()
    userName: string;

    @required()
    password: string;

    @compare({fieldName:'password'})
    confirmPassword:string;

}
```

Here is the Component code, For creating a formgroup you have to use RxFormBuilder.

```js
export class UserAddComponent implements OnInit {

    userFormGroup: FormGroup
    user:User;
    constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = new User();
        this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.formGroup(this.user);
    }
}
```

Finish. Bind the html as per you custom need.

**[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/complete-rxweb-required-validation-add-angular-reactive-8cbwss?embed=1&file=src/app/user/add/user-add.component.ts)**