# Reactive Forms correctly convert Form Value to Model Object as List

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to convert the submitted form to an object.

I have been using the following post for guidance.

[Reactive Forms correctly convert Form Value to Model Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997765/reactive-forms-correctly-convert-form-value-to-model-object)

However, the example is only for a single object and not a list of objects.

I have a `Person` object.

**person.ts**

```
export class Person {
    public constructor(init?: Partial<Person>) {
      Object.assign(this, init);
    }
    x: number;
    y: number;
    personId: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    companyName: string;
    staffCode: string;
  }
```

Here I submit the form, and try convert it to a `Person` object.

**approval-edit.component.ts**

```
  public onSubmit(): void {
    const data: any = this.approvalEditFormGroup.value;
    console.log(data);
    this.person = new Person(this.approvalEditFormGroup.value);
    console.log(this.person);
  }
```

Result:

[image]

**Question**

How do I convert the `this.approvalEditFormGroup.value` into a list of `Person` (`Person[]`)?

```
persons: Person[] = convert(this.approvalEditFormGroup.value);
```

Comment: Are the form value returns array of persons according to first object in your screenshot ?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is a result of the `console.log` in the approval-edit.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map of the form value and create new instance of the Person class on every item in form value
something like this

```
const data: any = this.approvalEditFormGroup.value;

persons: Person[] = Object.keys(data).map(key => new Person(data[key]));
```