# How to get to the $response property in the AWS SQS SendMessageResult with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I'm sending a message to an SQS queue as follows in typescript:

```
const queueName = 'some_queue_name';
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';

const sqs = new AWS.SQS();
const SendMessageRequest: AWS.SQS.SendMessageRequest = {
  MessageBody: JSON.stringify({ foo, bar }),
  QueueUrl: queueName,
};

try {
  const request = sqs.sendMessage(SendMessageRequest, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
    } 
  });

  const smgResponse: SendMessageResult = await request.promise();

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  expect(err).toBeUndefined();
}
```

At runtime, the `SendMessageRequest` shows a `$response` property but this isn't visible in the object definition. What is the best way to access this property at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [type assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13204759/8289918):

```
const smgResponse = await request.promise() as SendMessageResult & {$response: unknown}
```

Replace `unknown` with whatever type `$response` is at runtime.

If you are doing a lot of assertions you could create a new type for this:

```
interface SendMessageResultWithResponse extends {
  $response: unknown
}

// alternatively type SendMessageResultWithResponse = SendMessageResult & {$response: unknown}

const smgResponse = await request.promise() as SendMessageResultWithResponse
```